# Entity framework uses a lot of memory

Tags: c#, .net, performance, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Here is a image from the ANTS memory profiler. It seens that there are a lot of objects hold in memory. How can I find what I am doing wrong?

[image: ANTS memory profiler]

```
**UPDATE**
```

Here is my repository classes:

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class, IDataEntity
    {
        ObjectContext _context;
        IObjectSet<T> _objectSet;

        readonly string _entitySetName;
        readonly string[] _keyNames;

        private ObjectContext Context
        {
            get
            {
                if (_context == null)
                {
                    _context = GetCurrentUnitOfWork<EFUnitOfWork>().Context;
                }
                return _context;
            }
        }

        private IObjectSet<T> ObjectSet
        {
            get
            {
                if (_objectSet == null)
                {
                    _objectSet = this.Context.CreateObjectSet<T>();
                }
                return _objectSet;
            }
        }

        public TUnitOfWork GetCurrentUnitOfWork<TUnitOfWork>() where TUnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
        {
            return (TUnitOfWork)UnitOfWork.Current;
        }

        public virtual IEnumerable<T> GetQuery()
        {
            return ObjectSet;
        }

        public virtual IEnumerable<T> GetQuery(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes)
        {
            return ObjectSet.IncludeMultiple(includes);
        }

        public virtual IEnumerable<T> GetQuery(
            IEnumerable<Expression<Func<T, bool>>> filters,
            Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy,
            IEnumerable<Expression<Func<T, object>>> includes)
        {
            IQueryable<T> _query = ObjectSet;

            if (filters != null)
            {
                foreach (var filter in filters)
                {
                    _query = _query.Where(filter);
                }
            }

            if (includes != null && includes.Count() > 0)
            {
                _query = _query.IncludeMultiple(includes.ToArray());
            }

            if (orderBy != null)
            {
                _query = orderBy(_query);
            }

            return _query;
        }

        public virtual IPaged<T> GetQuery(
            IEnumerable<Expression<Func<T, bool>>> filters,
            Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy,
            int pageNumber, int pageSize,
            IEnumerable<Expression<Func<T, object>>> includes)
        {
            IQueryable<T> _query = ObjectSet;

            if (filters != null)
            {
                foreach (var filter in filters)
                {
                    _query = _query.Where(filter);
                }
            }

            if (orderBy != null)
            {
                _query = orderBy(_query);
            }

            IPaged<T> page = new Paged<T>(_query, pageNumber, pageSize, includes);

            return page;
        }

        public virtual void Insert(T entity)
        {
            this.ObjectSet.AddObject(entity);
        }

        public virtual void Delete(T entity)
        {
            if (entity is ISoftDeletable)
            {
                ((ISoftDeletable)entity).IsDeleted = true;
                //Update(entity);
            }
            else
            {
                this.ObjectSet.DeleteObject(entity);
            }
        }

        public virtual void Attach(T entity)
        {
            ObjectStateEntry entry = null;
            if (this.Context.ObjectStateManager.TryGetObjectStateEntry(entity, out entry) == false)
            {
                this.ObjectSet.Attach(entity);
            }
        }

        public virtual void Detach(T entity)
        {
            ObjectStateEntry entry = null;
            if (this.Context.ObjectStateManager.TryGetObjectStateEntry(entity, out entry) == true)
            {
                this.ObjectSet.Detach(entity);
            }
        }
    }
```

Now, if I have class A that holds records from table A, I also create class:

```
public class ARepository:BaseRepository<A> {
// Implementation of A's queries and specific db operations
}
```

Here is my EFUnitOfWork class:

```
public class EFUnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork, IDisposable
{
    public ObjectContext Context { get; private set; }

    public EFUnitOfWork(ObjectContext context)
    {
        Context = context;
        context.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
    }

    public void Commit()
    {
        Context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (Context != null)
        {
            Context.Dispose();
        }
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

And UnitOfWork class:

```
public static class UnitOfWork
{
    private const string HTTPCONTEXTKEY = "MyProj.Domain.Business.Repository.HttpContext.Key";

    private static IUnitOfWorkFactory _unitOfWorkFactory;
    private static readonly Hashtable _threads = new Hashtable();

    public static void Commit()
    {
        IUnitOfWork unitOfWork = GetUnitOfWork();
        if (unitOfWork != null)
        {
            unitOfWork.Commit();
        }
    }

    public static IUnitOfWork Current 
    {
        get
        {
            IUnitOfWork unitOfWork = GetUnitOfWork();
            if (unitOfWork == null)
            {
                _unitOfWorkFactory = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IUnitOfWorkFactory>();
                unitOfWork = _unitOfWorkFactory.Create();
                SaveUnitOfWork(unitOfWork);
            }
            return unitOfWork;
        }
    }

    private static IUnitOfWork GetUnitOfWork()
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current != null)
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Items.Contains(HTTPCONTEXTKEY))
            {
                return (IUnitOfWork)HttpContext.Current.Items[HTTPCONTEXTKEY];
            }
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            Thread thread = Thread.CurrentThread;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(thread.Name))
            {
                thread.Name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                return null;
            }
            else
            {
                lock (_threads.SyncRoot)
                {
                    return (IUnitOfWork)_threads[Thread.CurrentThread.Name];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void SaveUnitOfWork(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current != null)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Items[HTTPCONTEXTKEY] = unitOfWork;
        }
        else
        {
            lock(_threads.SyncRoot)
            {
                _threads[Thread.CurrentThread.Name] = unitOfWork;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how I use this:

```
 public class TaskPriceRepository : BaseRepository<TaskPrice>
    {
        public void Set(TaskPrice entity)
        {
            TaskPrice taskPrice = GetQuery().SingleOrDefault(x => x.TaskId == entity.TaskId);
            if (taskPrice != null)
            {
                CommonUtils.CopyObject<TaskPrice>(entity, ref taskPrice);
            }
            else
            {
                this.Insert(entity);
            }
        }
    }

public class BranchRepository : BaseRepository<Branch>
{
    public IList<Branch> GetBranchesList(Guid companyId, long? branchId, string branchName)
    {
        return Repository.GetQuery().
            Where(b => companyId == b.CompanyId).
            Where(b => b.IsDeleted == false).
            Where(b => !branchId.HasValue || b.BranchId.Equals(branchId.Value)).
            Where(b => branchName == null || b.BranchName.Contains(branchName)).
            ToList();
    }
}

[WebMethod]
public void SetTaskPrice(TaskPriceDTO taskPrice)
{
    TaskPrice tp = taskPrice.ToEntity();
    TaskPriceRepository rep = new TaskPriceRepository();
    rep.Set(tp);
    UnitOfWork.Commit();
}

[WebMethod]
public IList<Branch> GetBranchesList()
{
    BranchRepository rep = new BranchRepository();
    return rep.GetBranchesList(m_User.UserCompany.CompanyId, null, null).ToList();
}
```

I hope this is enough info to help me solving the problem. Thanks.

**`UPDATE 2`**
There is also UnitOfWorkFactory that initializes UnitOfWork:

```
public class UnitOfWorkFactory : IUnitOfWorkFactory
{
    private static Func<ObjectContext> _objectContextDelegate;
    private static readonly Object _lockObject = new object();

    public static void SetObjectContext(Func<ObjectContext> objectContextDelegate)
    {
        _objectContextDelegate = objectContextDelegate;
    }

    public IUnitOfWork Create()
    {
        ObjectContext context;
        lock (_lockObject)
        {
             context = _objectContextDelegate();
        }
        return new EFUnitOfWork(context);
    }
}
```

In order to use this, in the application startup I use structuremap:

```
  ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
        {
            x.For<IUnitOfWorkFactory>().Use<UnitOfWorkFactory>();
            x.For(typeof(IRepository<>)).Use(typeof(Repository<>));
        });
```

Comment: What do your queries look like?  `SELECT * FROM LargeTable`  ?

Comment: Additionally, what do your EF queries look like? Are you accidentally pulling many entities into memory when you only need a few?

Comment: You must describe what you are doing with EF, what type of application are you building and how you work with entities. Otherwise this question is candidate to be closed as not a real question because we cannot answer it.

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka: I am thinking what to post. I have planty of code.. I believe that select query will not tell much, I will post something.

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka, @Henk Holterman, @Julie Lerman: I added more info.

Comment: And where do you call `Dispose` of repositories and unit of work? Also make sure that you don't store any attached and proxied entity in session. If you store unit of work in thread or hash table where do you release it?

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka: The private method in UnitOfWork.GetUnitOfWork uses the httpcontext and not thread. Am I wrong? To be honest, this is my first time using the entity framework or any other or/m. I followed an article that present this pattern, I am willing to improve and fix the proble,s but I don't know how.

Comment: If you are using ASMX web services it should use `HttpContext.Items` but it will not call dispose automatically for you. So all resources are still in memory until GC collects them.

Comment: At first glance, this looks very overcomplicated...

Comment: @Joep Greuter: Do you have any better suggest? I have search the internet upside sown and didn't find any better solution. I will appriciate if you give a link to better implementation of unitofwork + repository.

Comment: @Naor: No, I don't have any better suggestions right now. And I am afraid that I don't have the time to find one as well... :(

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have a hunch you don't dispose the context.
I suggest disposing the context whenever you done interacting with database.

Use `using` statement whenever you create the context.

**[Edit]**

As far as I can see, you cache and don't dispose your `EFUnitOfWork` object. It is disposable, which is correct, but I don't see when disposable is called. Seems like you hold a reference to the context for all application run time.
 Moreover, you create and hold one context per thread, which will make it even worse.

I can't tell you for sure where you should put `Dispose` or `using`, as I don't know the usages.
You could put it probably to your `Commit` method, but I don't know if the `Commit` called only once during database interaction session.

Also, your design might be overcomplicated.

If I were you, I would:

- Find the way to dispose the context using current code, as a short-term solution
- Simplify the design, as the long-term solution

If I had time I would do long-term solution right away.
But again, I can't tell if the complexity of your design is justified, as I don't know how big your application is and what it does and what the requirements are.

Comment: While this is excellent advice for web apps and service operations (and other specific architectures) I wouldn't necessarily suggest that for every scenario (using and dispose). It depends on what the app is doing and what is creating the problem. There are client app scenarios where it is helpful to keep the context around (while keeping an eye on memory usage and abuse of EF cache). OTOH if this is a web app or service, .NET will toss the context any time the containing class instance goes out of scope.

Comment: @Julie - I agree that in some scenarios it would be preferable to keep context. However, I think that in the most scenarios it is more robust, scalable and less bug prone to dispose as soon as you can.

Comment: @Naor - Not clear from your code how EFUnitOfWork is instantiated.

Comment: @Alex Aza: You right - I updated the code with the factory that creates the UnitOfWork.

Comment: @Naor - added some comments to my answer.

Comment: @Alex Aza: Do you have any better suggest? I have search the internet upside sown and didn't find any better solution. I will appriciate if you give a link to better implementation of unitofwork + repository.

Answer (score 5):

Couple of things come to my mind:

- You aren't probably Disposing the ObjectContext. Make sure all your database codes are within `using(var context = CreateObjectContext())` block
- You have an N-tier architecture and you are passing entities from the data access layer to upper layer without Detaching the entities from ObjectContext. You need to call ObjectContext.Detach(...)
- You are most likely returning a full collection of entities, instead of returning a single enity for single Get operations. For ex, you have queries like `from customer in context.Customers select customer` instead of doing `from customer in context.Customers select customer.FirstOrDefault()`

I have had hard time making Entity Framework to work in an N-tier application. It's just not suitable for using in N-tier apps as is. Only EF 4.0 is. You can read about all my adventure in making EF 3 work in an N-tier app.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/ef.aspx

Does this answer your question?

Comment: @Omar AL Zabir: How do you know I am using N-Tire architecture? which architecture do you recommend?

Comment: Looking at your code, yes, there's no dispose. The UnitOfWork creates a Objectcontext on the current thread, but then it does not Dispose it.

Comment: I usually do this in my web app:
On Application_EndRequest, I loop through all items in HttpContext.Items and see which ones are IDisposable and call their Dispose method. This will then clean all UnitOfWork.

But even more architectural concern is, UnitOfWork should not be stored in Context. You can have UnitOfWork originate anywhere. It can originate on a business layer, inside some business facade method maybe. UnitOfwork is used within a using(...) block to clearly mark where the work starts and where the work ends.

Comment: @Omar AL Zabir: What are the reasons UnitOfWork should not be stored in Context?

Comment: UnitOfWork by design means a small unit of work done within a certain module. One instance of UnitOfWork does one and only one job. When you store it in Context, you are essentially reusing one instance of UnitOfWork to do multiple job. That means UnitOfWork becomes a stateful object and it is being used to do nonUnit work.

Comment: @Omar AL Zabir: Do you have better architecture suggest? Not sharing the UnitOfWork may cause creating nested UnitOfWorks.. One method may create one UnitOfWork where within there is other method call that creates another UnitOfWork..

Answer (score 3):

Do you clear the `ObjectContext` once in a while. If you keep an `ObjectContext` alive for a long time this will consume memory related to the size of the EntityDataModel and the number of Entities loaded into this `ObjectContext`.

Comment: @Naor: Just as Alex Aza is assuming. I don't see any disposal of the objectcontext / EFUnitOfwork. @Alex Aza: I agree with you that the design looks pretty overcomplicated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in a class which uses dependency injection, so the `using()` option was not an alternative. My solution was to add `DbContextOptions<Context>` to the constructor and as a private field to the class. Then, you can call

```
_db.Dispose();
_db = new BlockExplorerContext(_dBContextOptions);
```

at appropriate times. This fixed my problem where I was running out of RAM and the application was killed by the OS.