# ObjectContext instance has been disposed

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am using the entity framework the way described here:
[Entity framework uses a lot of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6010244/entity-framework-uses-a-lot-of-memory)

I realized I need to use "using" statement in order to work correct.
When I am doing:

```
                using (IUnitOfWork uow = UnitOfWork.Current)
                {
                    CompanyRepository rep = new CompanyRepository();
                    m_AllAccounts = rep.GetQuery().
                        Select(x => new Account(x)).ToList(); ///HERE I GET THE EXCEPTION
                }
```

For this example, I getting:

```
The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may be wrong, however the first that comes to my mind is that probably `UnitOfWork.Current` returns an already-disposed unit of work.

Imagine the following code:

```
void MethodA ()
{
    using (IUnitOfWork uow = UnitOfWork.Current)
    {
        // do some query here
    }
}

void MethodB ()
{
    using (IUnitOfWork uow = UnitOfWork.Current)
    {
        // do another query here
    }
}

MethodA (); // works OK
// now UnitOfWork.Current is disposed
MethodB ();  // raises exception
```

The question comes down to what exactly `UnitOfWork.Current` does and what is is supposed to do. Should it create a new object each time it is accessed? Should it keep a reference unless it is disposed? This is not obvious and you might have been confused by this.

Comment: You can see the source at the link in the question. In Ladislav Mrnka's answer he found out the situation, can you please read the comment I wrote him - I appriciate any help.

Comment: Why do you use `Hashtable`s then? You need to decide: either you should create a new Unit of Work (that is one-to-one with `ObjectContext`) each time you want to query something, or you should not `Dispose` it after each use. Which works better for you?

Comment: If I won't dispose the UnitOfWork/the Context, it will hold a lot of objects and this effect on the performance. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. What I mean is if you `Dispose` the context each time you use it, you should create one in advance each time.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the error speaks for itself. After any of your `**using** (IUnitOfWork uow = UnitOfWork.Current)` your "global" context is disposed. So any attempt to access it will result in error.

Comment: But why it disposed? I didn't disposed it before the end of the "using". Can you tell me in my code how I dispose it?

Comment: "using" construct it's just "syntax sugar" for try-catch-finally block, there finally block contains call to var.Dispose(); - see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx

Comment: I understand that, but when doing this: m_AllAccounts=rep.GetQuery().Select(x => new Account(x)).ToList(); I get the exception - before it reach to the finally section. So how the context disposed before??

Comment: As others already sad, then context must be disposed somewhere before that block. There can't be magic, inspect your code carefully and you will find where. Also this kind of error is frequently happens in multithreaded scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

I guess `ObjectContext` was disposed before you reached your `using` statement. Your linked question shows that you store context in `HttpContext.Items` or `HashTable`. If you wrapped all calls to `UnitOfWork.Current` by `using` only first block will work - all other will get disposed context from `HttpContext` or `HashTable`.

Comment: I think you right because only the first call worked and after that the disposed context was still in the HashTable. I was thinking to set the Context to null after disposing it so UnitOfWork will get null from the hushtable and creates a new one but I think this is a workaround and not a solution. Where and how do you think I should remove the current UnitOfWork from the hashtable?