# context is disposed when using "two levels" of context

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

When doing:

```
    using (IUnitOfWork uow = UnitOfWork.Current)
    {
        LocationRepository rep = new LocationRepository();
        Location loc = new Location()
        {
            CompanyId = m_User.UserCompany.CompanyId,
            Name = locationName
        };
        rep.Insert(loc);
        uow.Commit();
    }
```

I get the exception:

```
The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.
```

The reason I get this exception is that m_User.UserCompany is implemented like:

```
public _Company UserCompany
{
    get
    {
                using (IUnitOfWork uow = UnitOfWork.Current)
                {
                    CompanyRepository rep = new CompanyRepository();
                    m_Company = rep.Get(companyId.Value);
                }
        return m_Company;
    }
}
```

So actually inside the first using statement I create another using statement which dispose my context when done and I get the exception in the outer using statement.

I am using the entity framework the way described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6010244/entity-framework-uses-a-lot-of-memory).

What is the common solution for such case?

Comment: The problem is that both "usings" are pointing to the same object. So if one "using" block disposes of it, it's disposed for the other as well. Do you need to have the "using" statement in the getter of the UserCompany object? It doesn't look like it's being used.

Comment: @tobias86: CompanyRepository rep = new CompanyRepository(); is actually uses the unitofwork. UnitOfWork.Current creates an instance and stores it in the httpcontext, inside CompanyRepository I get the unitofwork from the httpcontext in order to use it.

Comment: Have a look at TK's answer below.

Comment: @tobias86: This is not an answer I can use because there are many places with this issue. I need to do some change in my repository pattern but I don;t know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder why do you even bother with repositories if your `User` entity access unit of work directly? Your architecture looks very inconsistent. Create central place where unit of work is instanciated and disposed - in case of web application ideal place to call these methods is beginning and ending request. Access unit of work from repositories (or pass unit of work as parameter to their constructors) and handle all data retrieving and data persisting in repositories. Don't make your entities dependent on unit of work - that makes your repositories redundant and you can fallback to active record pattern.

This all leads to dependency injection with per HTTP request lifetime for unit of work and repositories.

Complains like "it is lot of work" or "I have a lot of places to change" are not excuse. You have a problem and you have to solve it. Solution requires big amount of refactoring because your initial solution was wrong - I sad to say you did it wrong and now you must invest your time to fix it.

Comment: I don't care investing time of create the right solution. I never said I don't want to do something because it is a lot of work. TK's answer is not acceptable not because it is a lot of work, but because this problem appears in many places and use TK's solution is just workaround and not real solution. I am using repository patern to gain all the abilities for my enities and I use unitofwork in order to use more then one repository. I was looking in many patterns before I decide and this is what I found. BTW, I use this example: http://www.primaryobjects.com/CMS/Article122.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution would be to remove the using statement from the 'UserCompany' property. This would ensure that the UnitOfWork.Current isnt being disposed of prematurely.

Another idea would be to re-factor the property to a function that takes a IUnitOfWork as a parameter. e.g.

```
public _Company GetUserCompany(IUnitOfWork uow)
{
    CompanyRepository rep = new CompanyRepository();
    m_Company = rep.Get(companyId.Value);              
    return m_Company;
}
```

this then allows you to manage the life of the IUnitOfWork outside the scope of the function. e.g.

```
using (IUnitOfWork uow = UnitOfWork.Current)
{        
    /* Snip...*/

        CompanyId = m_User.GetUserCompany(uow).CompanyId,

    /* Snip...*/
}
```

This has the added benefit of allowing an external caller to the GetUserCompany() to always be able to manage the lifespan of the IUnitOfWork regardless of how its used within the GetUserCompany function.

Comment: I agree, this is much better.

Comment: This is not an answer I can use because there are many places with this issue. I need to do some change in my repository pattern but I don't know how.

Comment: Large scale changes might seem daunting at first, however, they are rarely as much work as it seems at the outset. Normally I'd argue that the benefit might not *always* justify the cost. However, in this case you're suffering from program crashes, you might cause yourself more issues down the road if you just went with the 'quick patch' option now. Obviously I haven't seen your code and I am unaware of the ramifications in making these large scale design changes. Only you can make that call!

Comment: @Naor: If you have many places with this issue the change is a must. Your architecture is not maitenable.

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka: I know I need to change something. I am looking on what exactly to change.